# Foreach activity in parallel mode running multiple times

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-data-factory

In my ADF pipeline I am executing a foreach activity containing child pipelines, from a lookup.

The foreach activity is supposed to run parallelly (Sequential Execution is not checked). Ideally if there are 10 rows as output to my lookup, the foreach should have ran total 10 parallel runs.

However I could see that the same 10 parallel runs have ran 4 times, so I ended up with each child pipeline getting executed 4 times instead of once.

Note: I have triggered via a trigger and there is no set variable inside the foreach activity which is used in the child pipeline. The attributes are transferred as @item()

Is there some properties that I should set to eliminate this multiple runs?

Comment: Before providing a solution, can you share the pipeline code (remove sensitive parts of course)

The possible reasons for such behavior are:
- the pipeline is being triggered four times at same time
- There's an ongoing issue with ADF backend (believe it can happen)
- or there's an issue with the logic 

would love  to help, TBH the code helps :)

Comment: Hi @PauloCorreia, you are right, there was another process running at backend which was calling the foreach four times. I have identified the issue and its resolved.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my comment :)